# new to json parsing - how to get an array within an array

Tags: java, android, json

from the following [link](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=nike&format=json) , I need to get the value stored in "media".

Here is my code:

```
Content = Content.replace("jsonFlickrFeed(", "");
Content = Content.replace("})", "}");
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("items"); // this works great!
```

But I can not access past "items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through the JSON like this:

```
...
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("items");

for (int i=0; i<jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

    String media = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i).getString("media");
}
```

This will loop through the `images` and return the value(s) in `media`.

In your case it should be something like this:

```
..
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("items");

for (int i=0; i<jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject finalNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray finalArray = finalNode.optJSONArray("media");

    for (int j=0; j<finalArray.length(); j++) {
        String m = finalArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("m");
    }

}
```

...because there is another node inside the `media` node, called `m`.

Comment: and how do i get that "m" stuff out of there ?

Comment: You can try looping through `media` in the for loop and then use `jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i).getString("m");` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example getting the `tags` string for each item in the `JSONArray` that you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String tags = jsonObject.getString("tags");
}
```

This will iterate through all `JSONObjects` that are in the array, and extract the `tags` field from each object.

Comment: jsonMainNode.get(i); gave me an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject

Comment: My mistake, use `getJSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("items"); // this works great!
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonMainNode.get(i);
                JSONObject media = item.getJSONObject("media");
                String valueMedia = media.getString("m");
                Log.d("TAG", valueMedia);
            }
```